# Continuous I/O latency error on ESXi 5.0

Tags: vmware-esxi, hp, hp-proliant

Recently I posted a question on **[HP Proliant DL180 G6 - Smart Array P410, bay 11 error](https://serverfault.com/questions/584829/hp-proliant-dl180-g6-smart-array-p410-bay-11-error)** which the answers helped me to dig through. And today that I just noticed under my vSphere log which gives a continuous I/O latency error as seen below;

[image]

As per my previous question, I'm not sure whether this happens due to one drive has been corrupted or missing according to the array controller. Our server is on a RAID 6 and I'm waiting until I get the NAS set-up, so that I can back up all the VM(s), then replace the effected disk.

What I also would like to know is that, to re-initialize a disk on RAID 6, do I have to remove it & re-add when the server is on or to do it once shut downed?? I'm sorry, I'm quiet unsure I don't have much more experience on RAID to be honest.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please don't wait as it might be to late when you finally do switch it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are receiving latency errors because the array is degraded due to a failed disk.

All you need to do at this point is obtain a replacement disk and insert it into drive slot #1. **That is all**. This can be done with the server on. No initialization, no formatting. You don't need to back up your VMs. **Just replace the disk as soon as possible.**

Comment: While it's not necessary per se for reconstructing a RAID, having a backup of your data is *always* a good idea, but that should have been done before the disk was dying. So, at least do it afterwards. And note that performance will be degraded during the rebuild as well, so don't expect that this warning will go away immediately after replacing the disk.

Comment: Thank you. I've ordered a new HP disk & I'll be replacing it soon.