# How to check HP Smart array status on ESXi 5

Tags: raid, vmware-esxi, hp, hp-smart-array

I've been reading **[How to run the HP Online ACU CLI for Linux in ESXi 4.x](http://www.v-front.de/2012/03/how-to-run-hp-online-acu-cli-for-linux.html)** & trying to  figure out a way to see the RAID status of the server without having to restart it.

This is because, I've posted a **[question](https://serverfault.com/questions/584829/hp-proliant-dl180-g6-smart-array-p410-bay-11-error)** regarding RAID issue and got the disk replaced. I've also had a look into the RAID controller to see whether this is done but it reported that the status was still **Recovering**.

I cannot shutdown the server just to check the RAID status each time. Is there a way to get this fixed or even to see through ESXi CLI whether the RAID is functioning properly.??

Answer (score 1):

If you install the HP Offline Bundle or used the HP Custom build of vSphere, it will include the the CLI version tools of the HPACUCLI.

Not sure which version of vSphere you have, but [here](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.BINARYPORTLET/public/kb/docDisplay/resource.process/?spf_p.tpst=kbDocDisplay_ws_BI&spf_p.rid_kbDocDisplay=docDisplayResURL&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&spf_p.rst_kbDocDisplay=wsrp-resourceState=docId%253Demr_na-c03469595-2%257CdocLocale%253D&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken) is the user guide for vSphere 5.1.

If you need to download the Offline Bundle (or the HP Build Version of vSphere) you can pull that down [directly from HP.](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/servers/software/vmware/esxi-image.html)

Comment: I'm using `**ESXi 5.0.0, 469512**` and its not a custom build by HP. Its purely ESXi I assume. Well, as I mentioned the link on my question, I'm not sure what type of harm it will do if I install that.